# Proxmox не использует кастомный lxc шаблон при создании контейнера

Tags: linux, администрирование, виртуализация, lxc, proxmox

При создании собственного шаблона lxc - proxmox отказывается делать на основе его новые виртуалки вываливая следующее:

```
Using default stripesize 64.00 KiB.
Logical volume "vm-100-disk-1" created.
mke2fs 1.44.3 (10-July-2018)
Discardindone
Creating filesystem with 2097152 4k blocks and 524288 inodes
Filesystem UUID: 5d45a865-bfc5-4368-8b88-710a39856a3d
Superblock backups stored on blocks:
32768, 98304, 163840, 229376, 294912, 819200, 884736, 1605632

Allocating group tabdone
Writing inode tabdone
Creating journal (16384 blocks): done
Multiple mount protection is enabled with update interval 5 seconds.
Writing superblocks and filesystem accounting informatdone

extracting archive '/var/lib/vz/template/cache/snap-test-03-2018-08-04.tar.gz'
Total bytes read: 407459840 (389MiB, 86MiB/s)
Architecture detection failed: open '/bin/sh' failed: No such file or directory

Falling back to amd64.
Use `pct set VMID --arch ARCH` to change.
Logical volume "vm-100-disk-1" successfully removed
TASK ERROR: unable to detect OS distribution
```

При использовании шаблонов с https://linuxcontainers.org/ - всё прекрасно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема в неправильных (применительно к proxmox во всяком случае) советах в интернете.

1. Никто не советует добавить в шаблон пакет `dash`, который предоставляет `/bin/sh`
2. При сжатии НЕ НАДО запаковывать `/var/lib/lxc/<имя контейнера>`. Надо запаковывать `/var/lib/lxc/<имя контейнера>/rootfs`. В полученном архиве созданном через`tar -czvf` НЕ ДОЛЖНО быть папки `rootfs` и файла `config`. ТОЛЬКО корень.

Примерный (но рабочий) скрипт для запаковки:

```
#!/bin/bash

CONTAINER_NAME="test-05"

lxc-create -t ubuntu --name "$CONTAINER_NAME" -- --arch "amd64" --release "bionic" --packages "dash,coreutils,python-apt,ssh,mc,nano,htop,tmux" --mirror http://mirror.yandex.ru/ubuntu

cd /var/lib/lxc/"$CONTAINER_NAME"

rm -r ./rootfs/var/cache/apt/archives/*
rm -r ./rootfs/var/lib/apt/lists/*
rm -r ./rootfs/var/log/*
rm -r ./rootfs/proc/*
rm -r ./rootfs/sys/*
rm -r ./rootfs/tmp/*
rm -r ./rootfs/var/tmp/*

cd ./rootfs

tar -czvf "$HOME"/"$CONTAINER_NAME"_"$(date +%F_%H-%M-%S)".tar.gz ./
```